# Как удалить все элементы кроме выбранных из listBox'a

Tags: c#, winforms

В начале юзаю:

```
BindingList<Class> data;
...
listbox.DataSource = data
```

Как можно очистить элементы из listbox'a которые не были выбраны при помощи контекстного меню ?
И при этом нужно очистить все данные кроме выбранного из листбокса элемента данных в классе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var notSelectedItems = data.Except(listbox.SelectedItems.Cast<Class>()).ToArray();
foreach (var item in notSelectedItems)
{
    data.Remove(item);
}
```

или

```
data = new BindingList(listbox.SelectedItems.Cast<Class>().ToList());
listbox.DataSource = data;
```

Но это странное действие, обычно операции выполняют с выбранными элементами, а не наоборот.